# Azure Logic Apps Export to file from paginated report not working 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-logic-apps, powerbi-paginated-reports

i have a simple flow in azure logic apps:
1- reccurence.
2- Export to file from paginated report as excel.
3- email the excel file.

but the second has an error, says Unauthorized code 401.

the power-bi paginated report is connected to my azure database server with the sql server crediatials.

note: the paginated report doesnt have parameters.

[image]

[image]

[image]

i hope you can guide me to a solution for that.

EDIT: more info

[image]

Comment: What is the license mode you are using?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin premium on power-bi, pay-as-you-go on azure

Comment: In the workspace what permission do you have? In order to get the data you need atlases builder permissions

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana i have the highest permission there is in the workspace, i guess its called Owner. does my organization have something to do here? blocking something?

Comment: Sorry I mean datasets have another permission called build and reshare. I think your Azure environment and powerbi is in a different tenant. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-build-permissions

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana unfortunately, i didnt find any build and reshare settings. please check the new photo i added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, premium-per-user is not enough to have access to export from power bi.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to
[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps. Seems like an issue with the dataset in power bi.

Got to paginated report and click on edit in PBI report builder
[image]

Click on edit credentials

[image]

Change authentication to OAuth and tick the box and sign in.

[image]

It is a bug in the API that can't pass through an identity token

Comment: unfortunately, OAuth2 doesnt work, only Basic with server login credentials. i tried Basic with checking the box, still no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately it requires OAuth authentication to work.